# "Top X% this month" - top X of what?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues, top-users

When you get the "top 0.74% this month" or whatever the percentage or timeframe is, what does that come out of?

Judging by how low the numbers are, it would seem that it comes out of the entire SO population, which seems wrong to me. I would think it should only be taken out of the population active this month (or whatever time frame.)

What is the denominator for the Top X% this  calculation?

Is the actual denominator consistent with the desired denominator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you click on the link, it takes you to the relevant [stackexchange.com leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) page.

The rules are explained in the side bar, the relevant bit being:

> users with less than 200 reputation
> are not tracked in the leagues

So, the ranking percentages only consider users with at least 200 rep on a site.

Comment: So, people who are not active in the time frame ARE counted? Doesn't this give a misleading figure? That means that if 20% of the community is not active in a given month (which is very, very common, and would not surprise me here) then anyone who gains rep is automatically in the top 20% for the month. That seems wrong.

Comment: And as time goes on and users go inactive, this number will only get less and less meaningful as the actual "live" range gets smaller.

Comment: @glowcoder - user's who haven't gained rep in a time frame aren't counted in a league for that time frame.  You can easily tell that from the league pages, as the # of users in each league are very different.

Comment: I see. That is inconsistent with the last line of your answer, but thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: @glowcoder - clarified in the answer.

Comment: @KevinMontrose : what does it mean on the "careers" site.  Mine sais "top 20% java" --- I have no idea what that means .

Comment: What about those users who lost their reputation during current month? I think you should compete with those whose gain was greater than 0. Or maybe also add last logged on at least 7 days ago (or another interval). Otherwise you may have people who haven't logged on for years, and their reputation is growing, because they keep being upvoted. Makes no point to compete against them.

Answer (score 7):

1. Take the percentage from the profile, its precision are [two fractional significant digits](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_precision); in the example it's 0,59%:

   [image: screenshot of user profile percentile in reputation league]
2. Check your place in that reputation league, in the example it's 3113:

   [image: screenshot of user position in reputation league]
3. Check the total number of users ranked in the reputation league by going to the last page of the ranking, in the example it's 529687:

   [image: screenshot of user in last position on the last page of the reputation league]
4. Divide your place by the total number of ranked users and round for the two significant digits:

   ```
   3113 / 529687 = 0.0058770...
   ```
5. After rounding for 2 fractional digits precision, and written as a percentage:

   ```
   0.005877 ≃ 0.59%
   ```

**[Q.E.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.)**

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is calculated correctly. It is 0.59% of *this year* and only *users with above 200 rep*. You are 0.59% out of the users in the league, not the total users in the whole stack overflow. Most users are under 200 rep and therefore do not appear in the leagues.