# Top 7% this quarter -> where to find all the stats?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

On my [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369009/jan-r%C3%BCegg) I can see a link "top 7% this quarter".

When I click on it, some rankings appear. However, the "top 7%" is nowhere to be found. I can also switch to "month", "week" or "all time" pages. However, I can't find out what "top X% this week" is, for example.

Comment: Your rank places you in the top 7%; e.g. you are ranked higher than 93% of users listed in the current quarter rankings.

Comment: Related: [What's the exact mathematical formula of calculating "top n% of this X"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126646), ["Top X% this month" - top X of what?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82961) and [Top X% in profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81589)

Comment: @Martijn: Yes, I know how it is calculated. But how do I find out the percentage? The percentage for "top X% this quarter" is shown in my profile page, where can I find the percentage of "top X% this week"?

Comment: You can't; that information is not published anywhere else.

Comment: Ah, then that's the answer. So you always only see the percentage per quarter, then? Because I thought I saw the all time percentage somewhere, but I can't remember where exactly...

Comment: No, it picks your 'best' ranking, daily after building the leagues; it could be that your percentage for the week is better, in which case that is shown, etc. I am not certain how 'better' is determined though.

Comment: See [What determines which bracket is shown in your profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81246)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your profile only ever shows your 'best' ranking; your lowest percentage across all the leagues. See [What determines which bracket is shown in your profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81246)

Your other percentages are all going to be higher (worse), but the numbers are not visible anywhere. You can easily calculate these yourself, taking your current position in each league, as well as the number of users listed (see the last page of each league):

- Weekly: you are not ranked yet this week (you did not earn reputation this week before today)
- Monthly: you are not ranked yet this week (you did not earn reputation this month before today)
- Quarterly: ranked #8640 out of 140344 users ranked: 6.16%
- Yearly: ranked #55789  out of 186148 users ranked: 29.97%
- Overall: ranked #58550 out of 191314 users ranked: 30.60%

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what I wanted to know!